# Validating Service Prinicipal Name (SPN) from Azure AD using .NET SDK

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, adal, microsoft-account

I have a requirement to get the properties of a SPN from Azure AD using .NET SDK. I need to validate if SPN is valid SPN in Microsoft Directory or not. How can I achieve using .NET SDK or Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: ADAL is an authentication library for Azure AD, not an API. It provides a wrapper around the AAD OAuth endpoints and is used to obtain an access token you need to call _into_ other APIs.

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur  Thanks for your response, is there any way we can do it sing .NET SDK or any other way. My requirement is to validate if given string is a valid SPN or not from Microsoft AAD .

Comment: You could use Microsoft Graph or PowerShell. If it's just a couple, you can also just search for it in the Azure AD portal.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize Microsoft Graph for this. Once you have access to read directory data, the following rest call will fetch you all the service principals

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals